# Dart Basics I would like to use the while statement to split each character and output it vertically, but it appears together with the previous output

Tags: flutter, dart

#### Assumptions and what you want to achieve

Please describe your question in detail here.
This is a basic Dart question.
I'd like to use a while statement to split characters one by one and output them vertically, but they appear together with the previous output.
I'm not sure how to do this, so I'd like to see the output result.)

#### Problems and error messages

There are no errors.

#### There are no error messages.

```dart
void main() {
  String test='This is a test';
  stringCut(test);
}

StringCut(String a){

  

  for ( int textlong =a.length;textlong>=0; textlong--) {

    print(a.substring(textlong));


   

  }

}
```

#### Output.

**current**.

> is
> is
> The output is
> This is a test.
> It is > test.

**Ideal**

> is
> In
> In
> S
> Te

#### Things I've tried

Re-examined the use of subString and the while function.

Comment: Hi mike. Welcome to stackoverflow. 
Could you clear up the inputs and outputs you are expecting from your code because its a little hard to grasp what you are trying to do exactly. 

Also the loop is a for loop and you mention using a while loop. So there is that as well.
Just try to describe the problem better and you will get help quicker.

Comment: I'm sorry.
I miswrote the output.
However, one answer has solved the problem.
Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

`subtring` can take 2 parameters, the beginning of the substring and the end so you can do this

```dart
for ( int textlong = a.length; textlong > 0; textlong--) {
   print(a.substring(textlong-1, textlong));
}
```

to individually print characters one after the other.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I see!
So it's a substring that outputs to the end if you don't negate the range?
I have solved the problem.
Thank you very much!

Comment: Yea if you don't specify the second parameter, the substring goes till the end. If my answer fully answers your question, please consider marking it as accepted (the checkmark under the votes).